# Where is title or app name for sails.js (using node.js and express.js)?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm trying to change my websites name.
Can't find where I can set title or app name.

Answer (score 21):

You can create any file in `config/` directory, for example `config/app.js` which contains comething like this:

```
module.exports = {
    appName : 'My App'
};
```

Any property of exported object become an option of Sails` config.

`appName` property is used as application title. For example, in default layout:

```
<title><%- title %></title>
```

where `title` === `sails.config.appName` === `'My App'`

By default `appName` config variable is set to 'Sails'.

Comment: is right.  To add to that, on a per-view/controller basis, you can also override the `title` local by passing it into your call to res.view, e.g. `res.view({ title: 'Login to PuppyPortal' })`

Comment: just to make a quick note... for this to work in deployment without issues with default ejs template engine, remember to route the url to the controller in config/routes.js instead of just the view. If not it will not go through the controller and you will not be able to dynamically change title per page for SEO Value.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a good answer at the sails github [issues#768](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/768).

Adding app name at the app.js and bootstrap.js file works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

To customise your app's name simply add the following to the `module.exports = { … }` block in the file `config/local.js`

```
appName : 'My Brilliant App',
```

You can also override the page's title within your controller by passing in your own `title` value to the `view` renderer.

```
res.view({title: 'My brilliant title'});
```

and, to be SEO friendly, in your `jade` template specify

```
head
  title= sails.config.appName + " | " + title
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Sails 1.2.2, you may change the app name in `\views\layouts\layout.ejs` on line 4: `<title>Your App Name</title>`.