# where I create or modify global variables of the view (ejs)

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, ejs

I need to modify the variable "`<%= title %>`", but I don't know where they are creating the variable or where I can change it.

I will like to know that  other global variables can be found in the view, for example the variable <%= session %> I did not send in view, but for some reason already there. in "express" it had touched me do something like the following:

"`res.render('session/new', {title: "Log in", session: req.session});`"

so I'd like to know where they are creating the "session" variable, because I do not like to go out there not knowing some things XD

thank you very much in advance for the help.

Comment: What version of sails.js are you using? If I put `<%= title %>` in my _.ejs_ file, I get undefined.

Comment: I'm using version 0.9. 

The variable "title" is used in layout.ejs, in the title of the page

Comment: Ah, alright. That explains it, i'm using version 0.10. Probably removed that global variable in the latest version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is title or app name for sails.js (using node.js and express.js)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292415/where-is-title-or-app-name-for-sails-js-using-node-js-and-express-js)

Answer (score 5):

I will try to answer some of your questions regarding local/global variables in *Sails.js*.

**Local variables**

*Sails.js* is built on top of *ExpressJS* and uses much of the same techniques for sending data to the view. For example, to send local variables to the view in context:

In your controller:

```
newSession: function(req, res, next) {
    res.view('session/new', {
        title: "Log in", 
        session: req.session
    });
});
```

**Global variables**

*Sails.js* have already some global variables. `title` maybe one of them. For example `sails` is a global variable. To that variable you can attach your own custom variables. To do that:

- Create a new file in *config* folder.
- Name it whatever you like, and use the *module.exports* convention.

In your `config/myGlobals.js` file:

```
module.exports.myGlobalVariables = {
    globalOne: "This is a string",
    globalTwo: function(){ return "myGlobal"; }
}
```

Now you can access these variables in all your controllers/views using:

```
sails.config.myGlobalVariables.globalOne; //returns: This is a string
sails.config.myGlobalVariables.globalTwo; //returns: myGlobal
```

Comment: That was very helpful, @aludvigsen. However, after creating the config/myGlobals.js file, how can I use **sails.config.myGlobalVariables.globalOne** inside views/layout.ejs?